# Application for cataloguing a media collection?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, media-manager

I'd like to catalog a collection audio or video pieces, e.g. audio or video recordings. I'd like to keep some meta-data, as well as categorize, tag and rate - with arbitrary categories, tags and rating scales I define.

Required features:

- Supports x86_64 platforms
- Runs on Linux
- Either fully GUI-based or with a GUI
- Not inextricably integrated with a specific desktop environment
- Gratis
- Libre

Desired features:

- Actively maintained
- Supports complex searches using the user-defined categories, tags, and ratings

Answer (score 1):

**[Data Crow](http://www.datacrow.net/)** is general purpose media cataloger, while not specifically made for media files it can certainly be used as a audio/video library.

Never used it myself but there are predefined templates, plus you can as far as I know freely create arbitrary fields for your data and personalized data.

**[Treeline](http://treeline.bellz.org/)** is a some sort of outliner/database application with a tree structure and fully customizable data types and fields. You can create custom fields to holds any type of data (tags, ratings, categories, etc) A specific *File* field can pointg to your media files (absolute paths, relative, or web link).

Search can be a little cumbersome, but advaced features allow freely searching and filter with random criteria.

**[Tiddlywiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/)** could also be used for such catalog, using tags to categorize and rate your files as desired. Powerfull scripting features would allow to extend its functionality to add custom fields, and display data as desired.

It is web based and runs out of a regular browser on most platforms, or node.js instance if so desired. Can optionally be uploaded elsewhere.

If I am not mistaken most of these would probably require some form of manual indexing of files since non of them are actually dedicated media libraries with disk scraping capabilities. This might be considerably lessened if you can arrange all files to catalog in some form of list of paths/URLs.

You can then feed these in CSV or some other digestible form that can more easily be imported.